# Basic Auth through Ajax for accessing a page secured with https without entering Username and Password in dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need to access and  display a website page hosted on this url - https://xxxxx.com , without any authentication dialog box from my applicattion hosted in the same network.But i am not able to bye - pass the dialog box to enter username and password.

I used  Basic Auth for Authorization and it works fine with Postman.I get a successful response in Postman by supplying the Basic Auth value in header as Authorization.The same encrypted value for Basic Auth, i used in Springboot code to fetch some details from that page and it works fine too.

But when i tried to navigate/display this page using  tag and Javascript , after setting the required headers for Basic Auth, i am getting the error response and unauthorized - 401 with message - 
   WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Please sign in with your Office email userid (without the @xxx.xx)"

I tried different ajax combinations but not getting 200 code ,and it always ask to enter dialog box asking me to enter username and password.Otherwise ends up in 401.

Below is the code used.

```
function handleSubmit(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://xxxxxx.com/se/',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Type':'application/json',

            },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            data: '',
             beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic cmlqdS5mcmFuY2lzOkN1cmlwczIxxxxxxxx==");
                  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
              },
            success: function(){
              alert('succes: ');
            }

          });
}
```

This is my form in HTML -

Comment: <form name="myform">
      <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="Update" onClick="JavaScript:handleSubmit()"/>

</form>

Comment: Can you just set the authorization header in `headers: {...}` ?

Comment: i have set that also but no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine after i modified to history.pushState({}, null, '/xxx.com') in my then function

Answer (score 0):

This is my basic code for Ajaxrequests. I use this to request a secured Dir on my Webspace. As URL i use a CORS Proxy with just to bypass Problems with CORS and get AuthAccess working.

Maybe you can try this for your application. If you get it to work without 401 Error and without asking for Login, you can work on adding CORS Header without using CORS Proxy URL.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
             function ajax() {
                user = "test";   //  Insert your
                pass = "test";   //    real Login here

                $.ajax({
                    url : "https://--insert-a-cors-proxy-here--.com/https://youdomain.here/secured/index.php",
                    type : "get",
                    cache : false,
                    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(user+":"+pass));
                    },
                    success : function (result) {
                        $("#result").html(result);
                    },
                    "error": function() {  $('#errorbox').html('Oh noo, Error!');  }
                });
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <input type="button" value="Request with Ajax!" onclick="ajax();">

            <div id="errorbox" style="background-color:red">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="result" style="background-color:yellow">&nbsp;</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am able to navigate url with the proxy , but i am still presented with a username and password , dialog box to authenticate, eventhough i am setting the Authoriztion headers.

Comment: also its not going to the success loop for me.

Comment: success loop will be executed without any errors... Can you access it with a Browser? Check User/Pass or try another secured Dir. Maybe make another one for testing only

Comment: i tried it with browser , but still not working , what you mean by secured Dir ,i am accessing from my localhost to another secured site - index.html file.

Comment: just a Directory with HTTP Authentification on a Webspace. www.MyHomepage.com/DirWithPass/index.php e.g.

Comment: i dont have permissions to that box which is hosted for creating a directory, for example - www.MyHomepage.com/DirWithPass/index.php , instead i need to access this page https://MyHomepage.com/index.php , with the credentials i have.

Comment: ok , it seems i am able to fetch the request with ajax, and its success now , but there are some other links in that html page rendered , which is  the one ask me to enter authentication details again ,  is there any way from the json response, can we render this html without asking authentication dialog again?